# Setting a value of select struts2 tag <s:select> in javascript code

Tags: javascript, struts2

i wanna ask how can i set a value of struts2 tag  in javascript.

I'm working in a struts 2 project and i use bootstrap for design. 
I have a many to one relation between two classes "Catalogue" and "Lignes".

In the relative jsp page that permit to add a "Catalogue", i have a bootstrap dynamic table with java script for adding a dynamic row.
In every row i should have a list of of an object,

```
 cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].id.catalogue.ID_CATALOGUE" class="form-control" /></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:select list="avantageList" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].id.avantage.ID_AVANTAGE" class="form-control" /></td>';
            cols += '<td><s:textfield type="text" name="catalogue.lignes[' + counter + '].DATE_DEBUT" class="form-control" /></td>';
```

but my javascript code does not rcognise the select in the second row

Comment: Post the javascript code you are referring to and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: We had this discussion; I told you what you needed to do. Since you're not using values, all you need to do is render what S2 would render.